# Why was this question closed as opinion based?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question

I wonder how is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21868906/493122) opinion based or *religious* exactly. I feel like there has been some overreaction from the moderator Robert Harvey.

The close reason states:

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

The answer (which has been already [accepted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1370121/493122)) can be summed with two concepts:

- `const`-correctness
- compiler-optimization

I can "accept" that it can be too broad, I definitely think it should be closed [as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1370121/493122), but opinionate... how?

---

Apparently the question was closed when the text mentioned a *religious war* between colleagues. Here's the original text:

> I'm having a bit of a religious war with a coworker regarding the value of declaring stack variables that are not meant to change as const.
>
> What are people's opinions pro/con this approach. I know what my reasons are.

Again, except for the mentioned war the OP is fighting against his colleagues, no trace of opinion based question. In fact the question (which, yes, is lacking the `?` at the end) is exactly the same as the one proposed now:

> What are the advantages in declaring a stack variable constant?

Yes, it mentions the word "opinion" but it is pretty obvious the OP is not asking for opinions since the question's purpose, for him, is to solve the opinions war he is fighting.

Comment: By the OP: In RobertHarvey 's defense, the original question did mention a religious war so I edited it.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian, so the fact that a religious war has been mentioned by the OP, the question is automatically *religious*?

Comment: Without the war, it's still "what are the advantages". To what end? In what scenario? Compared against what?

Comment: Compared against... not using `const`? To the end of having a better program? In any scenario? But then again, `I can "accept" that it can be too broad`.

Comment: @Jefffrey What defines 'better'?  It's turtles all the way down.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker, Not really. A "better" program is: more efficient and/or clearer to read. There's nothing broad in the definition. But even if the definition was broad, the concept of pro and cons are not, in this context.

Comment: @Jefffrey We can, of course, disagree.  Pros and Cons (by their very nature) stray out of bounds very quickly on Stack Overflow.  While this may not be what you want, it is the sentiment of the community and the design of the site.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker, [oh](http://goo.gl/bZJqA), [yes](http://goo.gl/rVkYD) [please](http://goo.gl/QV7dU), [tell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376732/what-is-pro-and-contra-of-using-play-framework) [me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298144/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-a-treeset) [more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350672/pros-and-cons-of-interface-constants) [about](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380663/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-icu) [it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889117/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-batteries-and-core).

Comment: @Jefffrey Notice how almost all of those questions are *really* old.  The sites standards have changed in this regard.  They were once allowed; now they're not.

Comment: @Jefffrey this comment from animuson suns it up nicely: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221949/why-in-the-world-has-a-question-on-algorithmic-trading-not-been-deleted-yet#comment721279_221949

Comment: @Jefffrey They are now closed. Thanks for bringing those up.

Answer (score 1):

The original question said:

> I'm having a bit of a religious war with a coworker regarding the
>   value of declaring stack variables that are not meant to change as
>   const.
>
> [...]
>
> What are people's opinions pro/con this approach. I know what my
>   reasons are.

OP doesn't make it clear what his reasons are. All we know is that he mentioned *religious war* and *people's opinions*. This was correctly closed as *primarily opinion-based*

The revised question says:

> What are the advantages in declaring a stack variable constant?

This was correctly reopened, because this question is asking for objective differences, facts if you will.

Comment: The first question has a little bit of background to it, but the two are exactly the same.

Comment: @Jefffrey I respectfully disagree. There's a huge difference between *what are people's opinions* and *what are the advantages*.

Comment: The original question is effectively asking pro and cons of applying const-correctness. The reason the OP included the word "opinion" is because of the background to it.

Comment: I believe the reason we have human moderators instead of keyword parsers is that the human can look past keywords and understand what is being asked

Comment: I think we should read just a little between the lines to see what the OP meant with "What are people's opinions pro/con this approach". And he was obviously not asking for opinions since the question's purpose (in the story) is to solve the opinions war he is fighting.