# Why in the World has a Question on Algorithmic Trading Not Been Deleted Yet?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, vote-to-delete, old-questions

I just came across "[What technical skills needed for algorithmic trading, HFT, etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457428/what-technical-skills-needed-for-algorithmic-trading-hft-etc)" and immediately voted to delete. But that begs the question - why is this question from 2009 still here?

Can we please do a better job deleting this and other old questions that are so totally off-topic?

Comment: did you consider historical lock for stuff like that (not that I am proposing it, merely wonder if this option was taken into account)

Comment: I didn't consider it. If I had considered it, then I would have rejected it immediately.

Comment: I guess it has something to do with the old SO, where the rule was not strict enough unlike current SO. Old questions like that tend to be locked instead of deleted.

Comment: I have a habit of finding an old "recommend something for me" question and going through the list of Linked questions at the right to find even more stuff that needs deleted along with it. The fact is, there's just a *lot* of crap out there and there's no magic button to find and delete it all instantly.

Comment: @animuson: "I hope I can depend on your vote" - anon

Comment: Why delete this? Seriously - is it hurting anyone or providing misinformation? It's _already_ closed - what's the big fuss?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum The problem with some of the off-topic questions remaining on the site is that they appear in searches and give some users the idea that the topics are acceptable when they aren't.

Comment: @MikeW wrt closed questions appearance in searches, you might be interested in taking a look at [As it currently stands, this summary is not a good fit for google](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217913/165773)